# Eject! Eject! [eject]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

[eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eject)

70 questions, no excerpt. [Talk to me, Goose](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277931/what-is-a-talk-to-me-goose-situation)...

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Ejecting a disc. Ejecting an app. Ejecting a USB drive. Not exactly related

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Marginally. You can write programs to do it

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not really. Eject is better as a keyword in the title as opposed to a tag

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

The most common on-topic use [involves ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308936/what-does-this-react-scripts-eject-command-do). But there's just as many [wanting to eject a disc from a computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700179/mac-with-a-dvd-stuck-inside-whats-going-on) (not all of those are using programming)

Comment: There's DLL injection, so there must be DLL ejection too, right?

Comment: Ejecting problematic floppies, cd;s, dvd's, sd-cards  etc. is usually performed with a paper clip.  In our modern online world it is probably safe to assume this is an alias of the clippy-js tag.

Comment: 'Eject' would be a great name for a new software development productivity app, no?

Comment: Then there's Dependent Ejection (DE) which is when you kick your kids out when they turn 21  :-)

Comment: Or `[eject] -t` (the option to eject a disk back then when I started ) ?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +71/-5. A1 (Saying disambiguate) +15/-9. A2 (Saying Yes): +25/-6.

Comment: @Walfrat These days `eject -t` will do opposite of ejection (will try to close drive)

Comment: My heart breaks for the number of potential puns missed from the title of this question

Comment: @NathanAdams Oh, I didn't [miss an opportunity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/380081/1). This is phase 2, so serious gameface time

Comment: +1 only for the usage the term "burninate" (Trogdooooooooor!)

Comment: @NathanAdams Puns get [eject]ed from the title when it's featured :(

Comment: [eject] the tag from the list and into the burnination pile!

Comment: @NathanAdams Users looking for puns when a burninate request is featured will leave d[eject]ed.  Any edits introducing a pun during this time should be r[eject]ed or rolled back.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +128/-7. A1 (Saying disambiguate) +18/-17. A2 (Saying Yes) +59/-8. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eject) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use [create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-react-app) for questions related to ejecting in the create react app environment.

## Progress:

The [eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eject) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=eject),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Beject%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Beject%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Beject%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Beject%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193987)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=380081)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eject) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eject) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eject) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 47):

The status quo isn't acceptable.  [eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eject) is at best a dependent tag containing [react-eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-eject), [angular-eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-eject), hardware interaction (eg ejecting a CD/dvd), and possibly others.  That's too many different types of things to keep in a single tag.

I recommend removing the [eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eject) tag, Questions can be retagged to [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react), [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular), [create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-react-app), etc. and leave "eject" as part of the question title and text.

Comment: Not necessarily disagreeing about the “overloaded” meanings of an [eject] tag, but that is *not* what is meant by a “meta tag”. A meta tag is one that describes the nature or type of the question, rather than its content. For example, [homework] or [beginner].

Comment: To add to what @Cody mentioned, [eject] probably falls into the category called "dependent" tags, where it is dependent on another tag to make it clear as to what "eject" actual means. (I think that meta-tags also fall into this broader category) Being a dependent tag makes it a strong contender for "burnination", as opposed to being an ambiguous tag, which makes it a strong contender for "tag disambiguation".

Comment: @BhargavRao when didn't dependent tags doesn't mean meta tag? If anything, that's a very explicit indicative that the tag doesn't work as the only tag on the question, therefore being a meta tag.

Comment: Uh, since the start of using that term, @Braiam?! Meta tags are a subclass of Dependent tags. Think of it like humans and mammals.

Comment: @BhargavRao no, meta tags are not undesirable subset of a desired universe. Never there has been that distinction. In all cases they are considered *harmful tags*. ["Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. \[...\] **These tags are a problem because people don't realize this and will often use that as the question's only tag.**"](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/434/24840) Dependent tags, or any of incarnations, doesn't have space on a sane tagging space

Comment: @Braiam, "meta-tags are actually a subset of .... dependent tags" is exactly what I am also saying. I admit that I used the word subclass instead of subset, but I am not a native English speaker. I am sorry for that.

Comment: [tag:eject] has 70 questions total. It's clearly not useful enough to warrant creating a specific tag for framework specific usages of the term.

Comment: create-react-app already exists... It has almost 2000 questions tagged. [eject] is not a meta tag.

Comment: Dan: I've taken quite a bit of liberty in editing your post. I made these changes because I felt that slightly incorrect information was hurting the answer, even though I think your suggestion is the correct one. The largest change I made was removing the recommendation for creating other tags because the final suggestion you settled on exists already as Travis mentioned. If you feel I have changed the answer too much, please feel completely free to simply roll back the edits or add back in parts you wanted to keep.

Answer (score 2):

> "Ejecting" is the process of setting up your own custom builds for your CRNA app. https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md

This seems like legitimate use to me as far as ReactJS goes. "*`npm run eject` will start the process of ejecting from Create React Native App's build scripts*" it goes on to say, which seems to me that "eject" is the proper terminology for creating native react apps.

The classical sense of the word "eject" also appears in this set of questions in the form of ejecting a usb drive in .net: [C# - Ejecting USB drive using DeviceIoControl command - Failing in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566746/c-sharp-ejecting-usb-drive-using-deviceiocontrol-command-failing-in-some-cas).

While some of this use is certainly not what I would expect from seeing the word "eject", that is the way it is being used. I do agree that it is not the same thing in all places. However, I contend that the concept of creating a native app or programatically ejecting drives is on topic at Stack Overflow. I also believe that the tag, given context, can be used to distinguish content more than if it were not present.

So, while 1 and 4 from [the Criteria for Burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) seem to not be compliant, it would appear that it is at least somewhat compliant with 2 and 3.

As such, perhaps it warrants clean up more than burnination. Or perhaps some sort of clarification on the different uses. It is very clear that eject in the sense of react indicates the creation of a native app. Perhaps the set of react questions should instead be retagged with [react-eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-eject). Removing the presence of react makes it rather clear that [eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eject) satisfies all 4 of the requirements on posts which are describing ejecting drives, as is the general assumption when one considers ejecting with a program.

Comment: Enough of the questions are about non-react items that I don't think leaving the tag under its current name is a good idea.  Either rename to [react-eject] or burn it.  I'm not familiar enough with react to judge if a [react-eject] tag possesses enough value to be worthwhile over tagging [react] only and then having "eject" in the question title/text.

Comment: @DanNeely - Please post an answer to that regard so it can be vetted by the community. I do not think we should flat out rename it, nor burninate it, as is explained here.

Comment: Angular uses the same phrasing, "eject" to get away from the CLI as well. This needs to be considered when looking at "non-react" questions in this set. This is why it makes more sense to cleanup and produce alternative tags for legitimate uses than to simply burn or flat out rename.

Comment: As a frequent React user, I think [create-react-app] would be more appropriate for these questions than [react-eject].

Comment: @jtbandes - I don't think that would work, since creating a react app is different than ejecting a react app.

Comment: But “ejecting” is a feature/concept in the create-react-app ecosystem.

Comment: @AndyJ - Post an answer explaining your point of view on this, it will be more productive than sparse comments. I am not attached to [tag:react-eject], it just seems it would be easiest to find for users who are expecting eject to be in the tag set.

Comment: The burnination criteria are garbage (being a collection of half random questions from a post by Shog that isn't intended to be a strict set of burnination rules), and saying it needs to meet *all 4* is complete nonsense. #4 is a subset of #1, anyway, and would you really advocate for keeping a tag if it failed #2 but not the others? How about providing an actual reason related to the usefulness of the tag? The tag has 70 questions. It is not useful enough to warrant the creation of framework specific tags.

Comment: @jpmc26 - I think you didn't read the post. I state that the content is on topic (#2), and I am not sure why you would call the rules garbage. Perhaps you should take a moment and compose yourself.

Comment: Even for ejecting devices, it makes little sense as a tag, IMO. There is no "ejecting" expertise; there is Windows API expertise with `DeviceIOControl`, there's Linux expertise with `eject` and more specialised peripheral-related commands; ejecting on other kinds of devices is again very dependent on expertise in those technologies, and not at all transferable between devices. Unlike [tag:regex] which is mostly similar between different environments, where I can answer most C# regex questions even if I don't really C#, I don't think the eject tag provides any benefit, even if restricted to HW.

Comment: There can be complications with ejecting hardware, so perhaps enough experience could justify expertise in that area; that said, expertise is not a requirement for tag existence, and if it were, then hundreds of tags would need removal. Many technologies have implementations which are not transferable between devices. I don't see what need there is to remove the eject tag, why spend the effort to remove context?

Comment: Those "complications" wouldn't be part of the expertise of a software developer. The software developer orders the kernel to order the device to run the eject routines. If those routines fails due hardware/firmware, the software developer isn't capable of effecting them.

Comment: @Braiam depending on how much leaks through the abstraction layer it might or might not be a concern of the application developer.  But the people who write the kernel drivers and hardware firmware are doing software development too.

Comment: @DanNeely please, show me a firmware level question. I've never seen one, not even in [unix.se]